# Error Could not find or load main class emma

Tags: java, android, jenkins, emma

I want to convert "coverage.ec" file to coverage_report.html, for this I am running below command

```
$ java emma report -r txt,html -in /Users/user.name/Desktop/coverage.ec
```

But getting below error

> Error: Could not find or load main class emma

Please provide any suggestion on which path I have to run this command.

Comment: Is your `emma.jar` file in the class path?